# Do i have to pay Zakat for plot which I intend to sell after sometime and use the money to buy a House

Tags: zakat

Assalamu Alaikum,
I could not buy a home till now as rates were always out of my reach and I didnt want to take loan from Banks and pay interest till I get old.

Alhamdulillah, I could buy plots with some money that I saved, with the intention to sell it in future (after few years) and may be own a House with the profit that I get buy selling that land.

Please let me know if have to pay Zakat for that land yearly or I have to pay when I sell it.

Answer (score 0):

For you to be able to pay Zakat, you must fulfill these requirements.

1. This must be ***your*** money, you must have full freedom in spending it.
2. This money must be extra and not needed for life essentials (food, home, transport means to  work, ...)
3. You must not be indebted to anyone.
4. 12 months must pass before you pay Zakat from you land money.

After you fulfill these requirements, then you have to pay 2.5% of your total land money each year for charity and the poor.

Allah knows best